# Resolving intermittent 502 Bad Gateway with Cloudfront pulling from S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

We have an AWS production setup with pieces including EC2, S3, and Cloudfront (among others). The website on EC2 generates XML feeds which includes a number of images for each item (in total, over 300k images). The XML feed is consumed by a third-party, which processes the feed and downloads any new images. All image links point to Cloudfront with an S3 bucket as its origin.

Reviewing third-party logs, many of those images are successfully downloaded. But there are still many images that fail. They are getting 502 Bad Gateway messages. Looking at Cloudfront logs, all I'm seeing is OriginError with no indication of what's causing the error. Most discussions I've found about Cloudfront 502 errors point to SSL issues and seem to be people getting a 502 with every request. SSL isn't a factor here, and most requests successfully process, so it's an intermittent issue - and I haven't been able to manually replicate the issue.

I'm suspecting something with S3 rate limiting, but even with that many images, I don't think the third-party is grabbing images anywhere near fast enough to trigger rate limiting. But I could be wrong. Either way, I can't figure out what's causing the issue - so I can't figure out how to fix it - since I'm not getting a more specific error from S3/CloudFront. Below is one row from the Cloudfront log, broken down.

```
ABC.2021-10-21-21.ABC:2021-10-21
21:09:47
DFW53-C1
508
ABCIP
GET
ABC.cloudfront.net
/ABC.jpg
502
-
ABCUA
-
-
Error
ABCID
ABC.cloudfront.net
https
294
4.045
-
TLSv1.2
ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256
Error
HTTP/1.1
-
-
11009
4.045
OriginError
application/json
36
-
-
```

Comment: Are you also using WAF?

Comment: @jordanm No, currently we're not using WAF, just security group rules limiting access to ports and such.